# Azure Public IP scheduled change

Tags: azure, dynamic, ip, azure-load-balancer, azure-public-ip

I've got an Azure Load Balancer with:

- Load Balancer fronend IP config: Azure Public IP (dynamic)
- Load Balancer backend pool: single VM

Is there a way to schedule periodically change of Azure Public IP?
Maybe using automation scripts? Or maybe I can create multiple Azure Public IPs and make LB to switch them periodically?

Comment: Do you want to change VM's public IP or Load Balancer froned IP or all of them?

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT, I need to change VM's public IP. I can use VM without Load Balancer if this required to achieve my goal.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I will give you the script. Do you want to use Power Shell or Azure CLI?

Comment: Power Shell. I have no experience with Azure CLI yet.

Comment: I add it as an answer. You could use the script to unattach or attach public IP to a VM. You could execute the script on runbook.

Comment: You also could create a crontab task to execute this script depends on your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You could use the following example.

```
$rgName = "shuilinux"
$nicName = "shui648"
$pipName = "shui-ip"
##unattach public IP on nic
$nic = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $nicName
$nic.IpConfigurations.PublicIpAddress.Id=""
$nic|Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface

##attach public IP to a nic
##If you want to create a new Public IP, use $pip = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name $pipName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $locName -AllocationMethod Dynamic -Force
$pip = Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name $pipName -ResourceGroupName $rgName
$nic = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $nicName
$nic.IpConfigurations[0].PublicIpAddress = $pip 
Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface -NetworkInterface $nic
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please add a code to set DNS name to created IP?

Comment: For a new public IP, when you create it add `-DomainNameLabel $dnsPrefix`, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.network/new-azurermpublicipaddress?view=azurermps-5.3.0)

Comment: For a existing Public IP, you could use `$pip = Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name $pipName -ResourceGroupName $rgName;$pip.DnsSettings.DomainNameLabel="shuilinux2";$pip|Set-AzureRmPublicIpAddress`